# Python GUI application to copy files one location to another location

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python but I have to create a simple GUI application to copy files. This is what I tried.

```
from Tkinter import *
from  tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames
import shutil,os,glob

def callback():
    src = askopenfilenames()
    des = "C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\des"
    sourceFiles = os.listdir(src)

    try:
        for fileName in sourceFiles:
            fullName = os.path.join(src, fileName)
            if (os.path.isfile(fullName)):
                shutil.copy(fullName, des)

    except Exception, e:
        print("Error %s" %e)

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()
```

When I run this code and trying to copy 1.txt file which is in src, I got following error .

```
The directory name is invalid: u'C:/Users/Ravi/Desktop/1.txt\\*.*'
```

I tried this code also to copy files, but it gives no result.

```
for files in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, '*.*')):
        shutil.copy(files, des)
        print("copied")
```

I have no idea, how to configure this application. What I just need is, when I click a "File Open" button and select files and copy selected files in to the destination (`des`) which I have hard coded(`C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\des`). Please help me to correct that code or find another solution for that matter.

Comment: I'd suggest using shutil more to handle the path and file. You need to look at os.path() https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html     If you were using python 3 (3.4) I'd say use pathlib

Comment: link for shutil docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Comment: if you know the file name, you don't need to use a wildcard like *.*.

Comment: Get you program working as commandline only, then modify it to use a gui

Comment: I'm just reading `os.path` and `shutil`. I tried the copy part separately. It works well. But I have no idea how to insert it into a gui @lxx

Comment: write it as a function or functions then just call the function/s from the gui. If the copy succeeds, have the function return true if it doesn't return false, then the gui can display copy success or fail messages. It can be easier if you write your application using a class or classes. If your copy code works, ask the question (new post) on how to add it to the gui or how to change it from commandline to a gui.

Comment: This is what I tried and this is working. [http://pastebin.com/1Wj49v8X ] This copy all files in **src** folder into **des** folder. @lxx

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for Python3. It is working fine.

```
import shutil,os

def callback():
  src = askopenfilename()

  des = 'C://Users//priyanka.rani//.spyder-py3'
  shutil.copy(src, des)


errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)# calling function to add in Tkinter GUI
mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

A full traceback would be useful, but I think your problem is this line:

`sourceFiles = os.listdir(src)`

`src` is set to `C:/Users/Ravi/Desktop/1.txt` (a file, **not** a directory) by the tkinter dialog and you're trying to do a directory listing of it:

`C:/Users/Ravi/Desktop/1.txt\\*.*`

Edit: You're also going to have problems with the following block, I think. You seem to be trying to concatenate two filenames together here:

```
for fileName in sourceFiles:
    fullName = os.path.join(src, fileName)
```

Comment: Yep, I tried the copy part separately, it works well, But I have no idea how to insert it into a gui.